# Ramification, integrally closed domains

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain, ramification

Let $L/K$ be a finite (I need only Galois, but I doubt this extra condition is really needed) extension where $K$ is of transcedence degree $1$ over $F$, where $F$ a number field.

Let $O_K$ be a Dedekind subring of $K$ and $O_L$ the integral closure of $O_K$ in $L$.

Is it true that only finitely many primes of $O_K$ are ramified in $O_L$ ?

Is it true if $K$ is ring of functions of some projective variety over $F$ ?

Comment: Whenever $L / K$ is finite and separable, only finitely many primes of $K$ ramify in $L$.

Comment: great! can you give me a reference?

Comment: generical étalness ? is this it ?

Comment: Presumably you want to assume that $O_K$ is not any old D-subring of $K$, but one whose fraction field is $K$ itself? That is, you don’t want this $O$ to be some Dedekind subring of $F$, surely. The answer to your question should be Yes in this one-dimensional case, since only primes dividing the discriminant will be ramified in the extension. But your question makes no sense in the final general situation, ’cause any of the rings in play will not be Dedekind.